# Object rotating via world axis and not local axis OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, 3d, rotation

So I have a function here

```
void rotateLocal(GLfloat deg, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
```

where x, y, z are the coordinates of a local axis you want to rotate around for this object. I am using (0,1,0) for testing purposes, but yet it still ONLY rotates around world y instead of local y. Here is the logic for one vertex of an object in this function:

```
ax = x;
ay = y;
az = z;

//normalize
length = sqrt((ax * ax) + (ay * ay) + (az * az));
ux = ax / length;
uy = ay / length;
uz = az / length;

//square these
uxS = ux * ux;
uyS = uy * uy;
uzS = uz * uz;

getx = vertex[0];
gety = vertex[1];
getz = vertex[2];

//find new vertex points using rotation matrix for local axis
vertex[0] = (getx * (uxS + cos(deg) * (1 - uxS))) + (gety * (ux * uy * (1 - cos(deg)) - uz * sin(deg))) + (getz * (uz * ux * (1 - cos(deg)) + uy * sin(deg)));
vertex[1] = (getx * (ux * uy * (1-cos(deg)) + uz * sin(deg))) + (gety * (uyS + cos(deg) * (1 - uyS))) + (getz * (uy * uz * (1 - cos(deg)) - ux * sin(deg)));
vertex[2] = (getx * (uz * ux * (1-cos(deg)) - uy * sin(deg))) + (gety * (uy * uz * (1-cos(deg)) + ux * sin(deg))) + (getz * (uzS + cos(deg) * (1-uzS)));
```

is there something wrong with my rotation matrix? Am I using incorrect variable somewhere?

NOTE: I don't want to use RotateGL or anything like that, I want to do the matrix math myself.

Comment: Not enough info, but you do know that sin and cos take radians, right?

Comment: yup, and it appears to work fine rotating around the world Y axis (so it actually achieves what I want when it is spinning in the origin) but it doesn't spin on the local object's y axis anywhere else like I want, it only spins around the world Y axis.

Comment: I added some comments to make things a little more clear as to what is going on

Comment: How do you expect this code to use any local coordinate system? An arbitrary axis cannot be defined by three values. You will always need a fixed point for the axis. If you want to support arbitrary positions for the axis, you need at least four parameters. Or is there already a local coordinate system defined somewhere?

Comment: Aren't you simply translating before rotating? ie: converting to worldspace before rotating. In OpenGL code you'd call: glTranslate before glRotate, if you want to rotate an object locally. Maybe I misunderstand. Also, you should use a library or create your own classes to handle matrices, this will just be annoying to yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are expressing the axis in world coordinates. What you have to do is:

- Get the local to world transformation matrix of the object you want
  to rotate.
- Use the inverse of this matrix to convert the world axis (in your
  example (0,1,0)) to local coordinates.
- Use the converted axis to compute the rotation as you are doing in
  the code.

I understand that the coordinates of the object are expressed in local space.

That's all.